# linux crond not working

Tags: php, centos, permissions, cron

I have a cronjob which for creat thumbnails. the folder `/var/www/html/work/` has permission `744`(I think 744 is more safe than 777)

Crontabs

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/work/images.php
```

php script

```
$newstore = dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/.$data->name.'jpg';
$width = (int)($data->width);
$height = (int)($data->height);
$desired_width = round((300*$width)/$height);
$desired_height = 300;
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);
imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($virtual_image,$newstore);
```

**EDIT**

In browser part. I have login into the `phpmyadmin` with `root`, So when I try `localhost/work/images.php`, it works well.`, and works in`/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/work/images.php`in`PuTTY SSH`.

but the job failed in `crond`. I have restart cron `service crond restart` all the thing [OK], then tried `/etc/cron.allow`, return `-bash: /etc/cron.allow: No such file or directory,` run `/etc/cron.deny`, return `-bash: /etc/cron.deny: Permission denied`.

BTY: `vi /var/log/httpd/error_log` there have no errors hint.

Where is the problem? `crond setting`? or `folder permission`?

Comment: When you SSH in and run `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/work/images.php`, what error message do you get?  I imagine that you're not able to write to the /var/www/html/images directory as the user you are running as.

Comment: Whats in php error log? Also wouldn't $newstore be /var/www/html/work/images and not /var/www/html/images ?

Comment: @cjc, @faker, thanks for reply. I used `chmod u+s /usr/bin/crontab
` and `chmod u+s /usr/bin/php`, now 
 `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/work/images.php` can work. but cron still not work.  I have restart cron `service crond restart` all the thing [OK],  then tried `/etc/cron.allow`, `-bash: /etc/cron.allow: No such file or directory`, run `/etc/cron.deny`, `-bash: /etc/cron.deny: Permission denied`. So at this time, my problem is cron not excused. BTY: `vi /var/log/httpd/error_log` there have no errors hint. Thanks.

Comment: `/var/log/httpd/error_log` is Apache error log - check your *PHP* error log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, god, stop chmoding basic system binaries.  No good will come of it.

If you're able to run your script from the command line as root, but it fails in cron, then the most likely issues are:

1) a permission issue (specifically, a basic permission problem, not something system-wide, which is what you're trying to fix with your chmod statements).

2) a PATH issue.

For #1, have you looked at the ownership and permissions on the /var/www/html/images directory?  Will the ownership and permissions on this directory allow the user running the cron to modify files?

Actually, how are you running the cron, in terms of the user?  Do you have it in the /etc/cron.d directory?  If you have placed the cronjob file in /etc/cron.d, then the format will be slightly different, in that you have to put the user who will execute the cron in between the date/time fields and the command.

For #2, I think this is unlikely, since you're specifying the absolute pathname of the executable (/usr/bin/php) and your script doesn't include any extra libraries.

Comment: I will find and fix my problem as your suggestion. I set the `php scirpt folder` permission is `744`. I do not want anyone can run my script. So how to `chown` the permission to `/usr/bin/crond` and `/usr/bin/php`? Thanks.

Comment: /usr/sbin/crond should have permissions 0755 and is owned by root, group root (so "chmod 0755 /usr/sbin/crond ; chown root:root /usr/sbin/crond".  /usr/bin/php has the same permissions, so the chmod and chown commands as above will also work.  /usr/bin/crontab is permission 6755, so you will want to use "chmod 6755 /usr/bin/crontab".  Ownership is root:root, as with the other files.

Comment: The php script folder will probably need permssions 0755 (744 will allow the non-owner to read the directory contents but not enter it; you need to set the execute bit on the directory to allow non-owners to enter it). The folder you're writing to should be owned by whoever is executing the cron job.

Comment: I have done change permssions 0755 for folder, chmod 0755 /usr/sbin/crond, chmod 0755 /usr/bin/php, chmod 0755 /var/www/html/work/images.php, chown root:root /usr/sbin/crond, chown root:root /usr/bin/php, chown root:root /var/www/html/work/images.php. But still not work for cron. I tried: `vi /var/log/cron`, there some lines like: `crond[3808]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/work/images.php)`, is this run well? or no? Many thanks.

Comment: The log entry shows that cron is running the file.  So, root is running the cronjob?  How are you editing the cron table?  Using "crontab -e" as root?

Comment: solved. thanks. `chmod 0755 /usr/sbin/crond ; chown root:root /usr/sbin/crond` is the right way. then except `service crond restart`, also should `service httpd restart`,`service mysqld restart`,  then the script run well :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your cron job to

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/work/images.php &>/tmp/job.log
```

this will capture any output from your script in `/tmp/job.log`. With any luck it will have the information you need to figure out what is going on.

Have a look in `/var/log/cron` and see if there are any related messages in there too.

Comment: I have add a new file: `vi /tmp/job.log`, and do the thing what you suggest, but now 15 minutes past, there still nothing in `/tmp/job.log`. Now I also try to change `* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/work/images.php`, still not working. BTW, my cron `crontab -e` is saving in `/tmp/crontab.XXXXZWOFCH`

Comment: No, what I said was change your cron job, use crontab -e to add `&>/tmp/job.log` to the end of your current job. Don't worry about where crontab -e is saving the job.

Comment: thanks. I have checked my folder again, I set the folder is `755` but my colleague set the script is `744`. he said `744` can provide custom run your script play a joke. So how to `grain the privileges` to the `crond` and `php` run the script as the `root` permession? many thanks.

Comment: A script needs both read and execute permissions.

Comment: yes, 744 is that the `root` has read, write, execute permession. but user/group only have read permession.